# Why does JPGraph LinePlot SetStyle draw a white line instead of the specified dashed red line?

Tags: php, jpgraph

I want to have a dashed line with a Lineplot in JPGraph. However, if I use the appropriate method the line is drawn white instead of the specified color.

I use this code:

```
$graph = new Graph($this->graphW, $this->graphH);

...

$lineplot = new LinePlot($this->target_data);
$graph->Add($lineplot);
$lineplot->setLegend($this->lang[15]);

$lineplot->SetStyle('dashed');
$lineplot->setColor('red');

$graph->Stroke();
```

And the result is the following:
[image: Broken code]

However, if I add the following to the code:

```
$lineplot->SetStepStyle();
```

The result is this:
[image: Working code]

So the question: **How can I get the dashed line without the StepStyle and why doesn't it work without the SetpStyle?**

Answer (score 0):

Do all of the line styling before you add it to the graph.

```
$lineplot = new LinePlot($this->target_data);
$lineplot->setLegend($this->lang[15]);
$lineplot->SetStyle('dashed');
$lineplot->setColor('red');
$graph->Add($lineplot);  // moved this to after the styling was done
$graph->Stroke();
```